# How do I Isolate users and their processes on linux

Tags: linux, security, user-accounts

I was working with one of my systems and set it to isolate users and their processes. For example:

```
[user@server] $ ps aux
```

shows only processes started by that user, *not* every process on the system.

```
[root@server] # ps aux
```

shows everything.

It works well but unfortunately I didn't note what I did and now can't remember how to reproduce it on a new server - this is not the default behavior on Debian or RH. Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: you ran one as `root`

Comment: No. The default behavior is for *any* user to be able to see *all* processes running (just like root) right back to PID  1. Try it on an unprivileged user. I remember it being a fairly simple change, just can't remember how it was done (or how to undo it)

Answer (score 1):

The main source of `ps` information is the /proc filesystem. It has a `hidepid=` mount option to make other users' processes invisible and a `gid=` option to exempt members of a specified group.

Normally procfs is mounted by the init system with hardcoded options, but adding an entry for /proc to the /etc/fstab file will cause it to be re-mounted with the specified options.

Note that hidepid= can cause issues with certain system services, e.g. systemd-journald or systemd-logind. Always use the gid= option together with it and add these services to the "allowed group".

Comment: Thanks, that's it. Documented in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Set in /etc/fstab:

```
proc /proc proc defaults,hidepid=2 0 0
```

gives this behavior and I haven't had any problems with any services. Thanks for the quick reply.

ADDED: This does seem to bork many of the services of KDE on a laptop but works great on a server.